# get fault when i using pdo to get mysql procedure

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i am trying to use pdo to get multi results from mysql procedure, 
i can get result from #1,but #2 will never return value to browser.what happened here?

by the way onequery is actually this:

```
public function onequery($query)
 {
     $this -> statement = $this ->dbhandle ->query($query);
 }
```

and rreultset is actually this:

```
 public function resultset()
 {
        return $this->statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 }
$mysql->onequery($sql);
    do
    {
        $rows = $mysql->resultset();
        if($rows)
        {
            if(intval($rows["laststamp"])>$lastTimeStamp)//get the max timestamp
               $lastTimeStamp = intval($rows["laststamp"]);

            if(in_array($rows[0]["id"],$messageUser))
            {

                  array_push($result,$rows[0]);
                  print_r(json_encode($result));//#1
            }
        }
        else 
          break;
    }while ($mysql->nextRowset());
    $result["lastTimeStamp"] = $lastTimeStamp;
    print_r(json_encode($result));//#2
```

sorry,i didn't give to much detail,the firebug just tell me this is a "500 internal server error",but i check the log file,there is nothing.
the form in the database like is

```
messages:
mes_id    formId    toId      mtimestamp     statue      msgText 
    1        18       19          1             1           ''
    1        18       19          2             1           ''
    1        18       19          3             1           ''
    1        18       19          4             1           ''
    1        17       19          3             1           ''
    1        17       19          4             1           ''
```

i just want to get how many msgText that the fromId send to toId
so the result should like this

```
formID MAX(mtimestamp) count(msgText)
  18          4            4
  17          4            2
```

so i write a procedure to do that,and it work well in phpMyAdmin's sql command;
here is the procedure:

```
BEGIN
 DECLARE  done int(1) default 0;
 DECLARE USER INT(11) DEFAULT 0;
 DECLARE USERIDSEQ CURSOR FOR SELECT  distinct fromId from messages WHERE toId = id;
 DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;
 OPEN USERIDSEQ;
 mloop:LOOP
     FETCH USERIDSEQ INTO USER;
     IF done=1 THEN 
        LEAVE mloop;
     END IF;
     SELECT fromId as id,max(mtimestamp),min(mtimestamp) as laststamp ,count(msgText) as num from messages where fromId = USER AND statue =1 AND mtimestamp > mtime;
 end LOOP mloop;
 CLOSE USERIDSEQ;
end;
```

Comment: What is the "fault" you get? An error message? You'll need to explain the relation of nextRowset() to onequery() and resultset(). Also elaborate on the data you expect.

Comment: where is the stored procedure